# What is the definition for a geographic coordinate system with east/west bounds of 0 to 360

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text, proj

I need the coordinate system reference or a projection definition that uses geographic (i.e. lat/lon) coordinates but instead of east/west bounds being defined as 180 to -180, I need them to be defined as 0 to 360. In other words Greenwich would be at 180 degrees longitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking [here](http://proj.maptools.org/gen_parms.html), you can use the +pm parameter to specify your own prime meridian relative to Greenwich, so using this command:

```
$ cs2cs +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +to +proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +pm=180dW
```

I get this:

```
0.0 0.0
180dE   0dN 0.000
1 0
181dE   0dN 0.000
179 0
359dE   0dN 0.000
-179 0
1dE     0dN 0.000
```

Which seems to be what you want.

I'm not sure whether this parameter will be honoured by all applications however. That page says:

> Currently prime meridian declarations are
>   only utilized by the pj_transform() API call, not the pj_inv() and
>   pj_fwd() calls. Consequently the user utility cs2cs does honour prime
>   meridians but the proj user utility ignores them.

So it'll depend on what you're doing with this CRS, and how the software you use goes about transforming points.

Comment: Thanks @MerseyViking "+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +pm=180dW" is exactly what I needed. I read about the "pm" parameter, but didn't understand that you could use it with a well known name.